# simple blob detection with kinect SDK

Tags: c++, visual-c++, kinect

as far as I understand the official Kinect 1.5 SDK, it comes with Face Tracking and Skeleton Tracking. How about simple blob detection? All I want to do, is to track a round / elliptic object. I can't find any code for that in the SDK, so should I use opencv or some other library for that?

(my code is in c++)

**EDIT1** is it possible to tune the face tracker so it would detect round shapes in general (instead of faces)?

**EDIT2**
here's depth processing code from an example shipped with the SDK. How do I get OpenCV to extract a blob from it?

```
void CDepthBasics::ProcessDepth()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame;

    // Attempt to get the depth frame
    hr = m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(m_pDepthStreamHandle, 0, &imageFrame);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return;
    }

    INuiFrameTexture * pTexture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
    NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;

    // Lock the frame data so the Kinect knows not to modify it while we're reading it
    pTexture->LockRect(0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0);

    // Make sure we've received valid data
    if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0)
    {
        BYTE * rgbrun = m_depthRGBX;
        const USHORT * pBufferRun = (const USHORT *)LockedRect.pBits;

        // end pixel is start + width*height - 1
        const USHORT * pBufferEnd = pBufferRun + (cDepthWidth * cDepthHeight);

        while ( pBufferRun < pBufferEnd )
        {
            // discard the portion of the depth that contains only the player index
            USHORT depth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(*pBufferRun);

            // to convert to a byte we're looking at only the lower 8 bits
            // by discarding the most significant rather than least significant data
            // we're preserving detail, although the intensity will "wrap"
            BYTE intensity = static_cast<BYTE>(depth % 256);

            // Write out blue byte
            *(rgbrun++) = intensity

            // Write out green byte
            *(rgbrun++) = intensity;

            // Write out red byte
            *(rgbrun++) = intensity;

            // We're outputting BGR, the last byte in the 32 bits is unused so skip it
            // If we were outputting BGRA, we would write alpha here.
            ++rgbrun;

            // Increment our index into the Kinect's depth buffer
            ++pBufferRun;

        }

        // Draw the data with Direct2D
        m_pDrawDepth->Draw(m_depthRGBX, cDepthWidth * cDepthHeight * cBytesPerPixel);
    }

    // We're done with the texture so unlock it
    pTexture->UnlockRect(0);

    // Release the frame
    m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(m_pDepthStreamHandle, &imageFrame);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the image you need from the Kinect feel free to use any image processing library with the result.

You can use OpenCV's [Hough Circle Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) to detect circles. You might need to convert from the Kinect image format to cv::Mat first.

I imagine OpenCV is not the only library with that functionality. If you're interested, lookup Hough Transforms in general.

I don't think tuning the face tracker is the way to go though.

Comment: thanks. I've added the exemplary depth processing code that ships with the SDK. How would I have to change the code, to have OpenCV run the Hough transformation on it?

Comment: Personally I haven't used the Kinect SDK much (since it runs on Windows 7 only), but a simple search should help. For example [Dennis Ippel's blog post](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2012/08/01/using-opencv-2-with-kinect-sdk-1-5/) or this [wiki article from Carnegie Mellon University](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/OpenCV_with_Kinect_-_Windows_SDK) (focus on the parts prior to Unity integration though). HTH

Answer (score 1):

You could use this, since OpenCV sadly doesn't support handling blobs by itself:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib